# knowing the width of total images of specific folder

Tags: jquery

I have images in two folders. One is in `tne` named folder and another is in `two` named folder.

```
/images/one/one.jpg
/images/one/two.jpg
/images/one/any.jpg
and more....


/images/two/any.jpg
/images/two/what.jpg
/images/two/ever.jpg
/images/two/images.jpg
and more....
```

And the images are in one div like this....

```
<div id="test">
<img src="/images/one/...." />
<img src="/images/one/...." />
<img src="/images/two/...." />
<img src="/images/two/...." />
</div>
```

**Question:**

Now I would like to know the width of total images of first folder named `one` and the width of total images of second folder named `two`

Is it possible with jquery?

Comment: If you can access the folder you can iterate by getting each image and see its dimension by `new Image()`

Comment: google + "php get image size" EDIT Or is it on client side ? How are we supposed to know ?

Comment: @Virus721 jQuery does not have server side version ( as far as I know)

Comment: And ? It doesn't mean the author understood that jQuery is client side only. And fyi there is phpquery

Comment: @c-Link , My comment is valid only if you know the file names of the  images.

Comment: @Virus721 well goodluck with mixing JS on server side.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick for you:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wwd3v/1/)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var dirs = ['sports','cats'];
    var widths = [0,0]; //Index 0 is width of images in folder 1 and index 1 is width of images in folder 2
    for(var i=0;i<dirs.length;i++) {
        $('img').filter(function(){
            if($(this).attr('src').indexOf(dirs[i])>=0)
            {
                widths[i] = widths[i]+$(this).width();
            }
        });
    }
    alert('Total width 1: '+widths[0]+', total width 2: '+widths[1]);
});
```

It's a little more advanced, but with the capability to be extended upon without much ado, simply by inserting more elements into the first two arrays.

**EDIT**
Forgot to mention that 'sports' and 'cats' are of course only example folders. In your case, you would need to put 'image/one' and 'image/two'. This also use very little jQuery, as it's not really a necessity in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var totalImagesFolderOne = 0;

$("div#test > img[src*='/images/one/']").each(function(){
  totalImagesFolderOne += $(this).width();
});

alert("Total width images in folder `one`: " + totalImagesFolderOne);
```

Here's a <kbd>[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mathijsflietstra/hA423/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `wrapAll()` function in jquery:

```
var allWidth = $('#test img').wrapAll('<span>').parent().width();
var oneWidth = $imgOne.wrapAll('<span>').parent().width();
var $imgOne = $("div#test img[src*='/images/one/']");
$('#test img').unwrap();
$imgOne.unwrap();

console.log(oneWidth) //one images width
console.log(allWidth - oneWidth) //two images width.
```